# Java video capture on Mac OS X (USB/Firewire)

Tags: java, macos, video, usb, qtkit

Looking for resources and information regarding capturing video from an external webcam on Mac OS X using Java. QTKit seems to only offer this functionality in native code. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: The last time I did anything like this I used the Java Media Framework. This was along time ago - so I guess that project is dead?

Answer (score 0):

The Java Media Framework is still the way of doing it, although you will have to download it seperatly from the JDK. It's available on sun's website.

here's a link to the API:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/guide/index.html[1](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/guide/index.html)